# C# with ClosedXML, First row is Treated as Header row

Tags: c#, datatable, closedxml

I'm trying to print A1 cell, it should print 'Tomer' but for some reason it prints 'Noam'.
Am I using the ClosedXML wrong? Or is there a different way in which I can get all data to DataTable as I can get the value with the correct cell address?

**test.xlsx** structure:

[image]

I've built a simple minimal C# console app demonstrating my point.

Program:

```
using c__closedxml;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Data;

string path = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "test.xlsx");

using (var wb = new XLWorkbook(path)) {

    var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.First();
    DataTable dt = worksheet.RangeUsed().AsTable().AsNativeDataTable();
    Console.WriteLine(Service.getValueByCell(dt, "A1"));

}
```

Custom function to log the cell content:

```
public static string getValueByCell(DataTable dt, string cell) {
    string refLetter = "";
    string refNum = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cell.Length; i++) {
        char curChar = cell[i];
        if (ValidateNumber(curChar)) {
            refNum += curChar;
        } else {
            refLetter += curChar;
        }
    }

    int col = GetNumberFromExcelColumn(refLetter);
    int row = Convert.ToInt32(refNum);

    Console.WriteLine($"Searching for column {col} by row {row}");
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[0].Table)); 

    return dt.Rows[row - 1][col - 1].ToString();
}
```

The table inside DataTable confirms that the first row is treated as a header:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt.Rows[0].Table)); // prints the following:

[
    {
        "Tomer": "Noam",
        "Cohen": "Aharoni",
        "31": 33.0
    }
]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You meant "header row", not "header column", right?

Comment: I guess(?), the first row of data exists as a heading for each row, although it is a row of data by itself and should not be appended to each row, I hope I'm clear with my reply

Comment: I only wanted to suggest that you edit the title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

`AsTable()` creates an Excel table using the first row of your range as column headers. This is like pressing Ctrl+T in Excel. `AsNativeDataTable()` converts that to a System.Data.DataTable instance. The rest of the rows populate the data.

Either first insert actual headers or use a different approach, avoiding the 2 conversion methods, to reference the data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will follow your recommandation(insert actual headers) first thing tomorrow morning. Really appreciate your reply!

Comment: @saraf The conversion to a table seems unnecessary. Why don't you just use `worksheet.Cell("A1")`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes it may seem this way. The thing is I have a bunch of classes working specifically with DataTable, it would be an enormous task to try and work with worksheet alone